# Trouble getting Mandrill Handlebars comparison expression to work

Tags: handlebars.js, mandrill

Template:

```
<h1>{{TotalEvals}}</h1><span style="color:#A9A9A9"><span style="font-size:19px"> Evaluation{{#if TotalEvals > 1}}s{{/if}}</span></span>
```

Output:

## 12

Evaluation{{#if TotalEvals > 1}}s{{/if}}

This is almost identical to an example they have on the Mandrill website [here](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content).
Any help on why the if statement isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that the conditional element of the if statement needs to be surrounded by back-ticks (`) like the following:

```
<h1>{{TotalEvals}}</h1><span style="color:#A9A9A9"><span style="font-size:19px"> Evaluation{{#if `TotalEvals > 1`}}s{{/if}}</span></span>
```

Comment: Nice one! Where did you find the documentation for this?

Comment: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content explains the backticks

Comment: Also here: https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/templates-dynamic-content/#handlebars

Comment: Get sure also that spaces in `TotalEvals > 1` are present as in the example, otherwise it does not work.